# WCF - How Can I Inspect The Service Contract Interface from a Behavior?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have some behaviors I'm applying to a service contract by attribute. The behaviors collect diagnostic information for logging/troubleshooting and are meant to be universally applicable to all our WCF contracts. The issue I'm having now is that I want to collect some parameter values during the execution of the contract (on both client and server side) based on custom attributes applied to the parameters of methods in the interface that defines the contract. I don't see anything in any of the inspectors I'm using that makes a sensible connection to the MethodInfo or even Type of the contract which I can use to get ParameterInfos. I had considered the possibility of a custom invoker, but even that doesn't seem to have everything I need? Any guidance would be appreciated. In essence, I would like to be able to find the attributes in a service contract that would look something like this:

```
[ServiceContract, RecordDiagnostics]
public interface IFrameworkService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Boolean AddOrUpdateCatalogItemAssociation([DiagnosticProperty]InstanceId catalogItemId, CatalogItemAssociationInfo info);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you implement `IServiceBehavior` in your attribute. If this is true, then `Validate` method contains `ServiceDescription` argument.

And `serviceDescription.Endpoints.First().Contract.Type` should give you the .NET type information - and from there you can access all methods/attributes.

Comment: Currently I'm implementing IContractBehavior but I imagine I can work through that much. That's half the battle, for sure. Now is there a reliable way to know which method is going to be invoked at execution time, either via an inspector type? I currently have message and parameter inspectors; knowing in the parameter inspector would be ideal. I may be able to work around this well enough as long as I can share the type instance with the behavior application methods.

Comment: All methods of `IContractBehavior` include `ContractDescription` argument which is equivalent to my suggestion about `serviceDescription.Endpoints.First().Contract`. So, just use `Type` property of `ContractDescription` argument in your `IContractBehavior`.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that property. Thanks kindly.